# Sub-function in grouping function using dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr, missing-data, counting

I'm using the dpylr package to count missing values for subgroups for each of my variables.

I used a mini-function:

```
NAobs <- function(x) length(x[is.na(x)]) ####function to count missing data for variables
```

to count missing values.
Because I have quite some variables and I wanted to add a bit more information (sample size per group, and percentage of missing data per group) I wrote the following code, and inserted one variable (task_1) to check it.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(DataRT, class) %>%
  summarise(class_size=length(class), missing = NAobs(task_1), perc.= missing/class_size)
```

This works very well and I receive a table like this:

```
   class class_size missing      perc.
   (dbl)      (int)   (int)      (dbl)
1      1         25       2 0.08000000
2      2         25       1 0.04000000
3      3         25       3 0.12000000
4      4         25       4 0.16000000
5      5         24       3 0.12500000
6      6         29       6 0.20689655
...
```

In the next step, I wanted to generalize my command by including it into a function:

```
missing<-function(x, print=TRUE){
            group_by(DataRT, class) %>%
                    summarise(class_size=length(class), 
                        missing = NAobs(x),
                        perc.= missing/class_size)}
```

Optimally, I now could write missing(task_1) and would get the same table, but instead NAobs(x) ignores the grouping variable (class) and I receive a table like this:

```
   class class_size missing    perc.
   (dbl)      (int)   (int)    (dbl)
1      1         25      59 2.360000
2      2         25      59 2.360000
3      3         25      59 2.360000
4      4         25      59 2.360000
5      5         24      59 2.458333
6      6         29      59 2.034483
...
```

So what happens is that the column "missing" only shows the total number of NA cases for task_1, ignoring the groups; and replacing NAobs(x) with NAobs(variable name) to fix this issue would ruin the purpose of writing a function in the first place. How could I calculate the number of missing cases per group without having to copy the code and changing the variable name each time? Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming that the function argument `x` gets evaluated in-scope within NAobs inside your function? Presumably you want to pass that as text and then... I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: You can simplify `NAobs` to `NAobs <- function(x) sum(is.na(x))`

Comment: You need to read up on non-standard evaluation. [Hadley has written some useful things about it.](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) Essentially, `x` will be quoted, so you need to use the SE `summarise_` version, for which you need to format your inputs differently.

Answer (score 0):

New dplyr update. The newest dplyr will be able to solve this with two new functions `enquo` and `!!`. The first quotes the input like `substitute` would, the second unquotes it for evaluation. For more on programming with dplyr, [see this vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

You will need the [developer's version of dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr), and I would also suggest [the newest rlang install](https://github.com/hadley/rlang)

```
#install developer's version until new release in May
library(dplyr) #0.5.0.9004+

#Setup
set.seed(143)
NAobs <- function(x) length(x[is.na(x)])
DataRT <- data.frame(class = sample(1:6, 25, TRUE), task1 = sample(c(NA,1), 25, TRUE),
                     task2 = sample(c(NA,1), 25, TRUE))
f <- function(x) {
  my_var <- enquo(x)
  group_by(DataRT, class) %>%
    summarise(class_size=length(class), 
    missing = NAobs(!!my_var),
    perc.= missing/class_size)
}
f(task1)
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   class class_size missing     perc.
#   <int>      <int>   <int>     <dbl>
# 1     1          5       0 0.0000000
# 2     2          4       2 0.5000000
# 3     3          3       0 0.0000000
# 4     4          1       0 0.0000000
# 5     5          5       3 0.6000000
# 6     6          7       3 0.4285714
```